# Html, Make the search bar wider

Tags: html

Im trying to make a search bar like google, i have it all pretty much worked out, im just not sure how to make the search bar wider, heres the code i have so far

```
<table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <FORM name="doingasearch" id="doingasearch">  
  <p align="center"><INPUT name=searchbox type=text size=20></p>
  <p align="center"><INPUT type="button" value="Search" onclick="return 

googleSearch();">
  <INPUT type="button" value="I Feel Lucky" onclick="return googleSearch

();"></p>
</FORM>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you find anything wrong with it, please say so

Comment: If by wider you mean the width of the input field, then change size=20 to something larger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either do it in your HTML:

```
<input name="searchbox" type="text" size="40" />
```

Or you could do it the right way, with CSS:

```
input {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You should refrain from tables when using search forms. Anyways, you could do two things here.

Either remove the `size="20"` from the searchbox `<input>` and change the `width` in `CSS` or you can increase the `<input>` `size`.

**like this:**

```
input {
    width: XXpx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>

<title>Search box</title>

<body>

<div class="searchbox" >
                <input style="height: 40px;" autocomplete="on" maxlength="100" autofocus name="m" type="search" placeholder="input text Here"  size="50">
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).